# Tabulate Area Using Multiple Shapefiles and Multiple Rasters

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, modelbuilder

I currently have ~150 county boundary shapefiles and have already clipped the statewide landcover data set by each county. My end product needs to be a table that contains either the total number of cells of each landcover class (e.g., evergreen, hardwoods, etc.) or a percentage for each landcover class by county. For example,

[image]

I tried using ModelBuilder to iterate through multiple rasters (Iterate Raster tool) but wasn't sure if zonal statistics to table was the approriate tool. Furthermore, I was unable to add an additional iterate tool so I could loop through all raster images and all shapefiles plus add this into a table similar to the one above.

Comment: I'm not sure you really need modelbuilder for this one. Maybe take a look at this thread: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/95433/how-to-calculate-a-percentage-of-an-area-covered-by-polygons-arcgis-10-1

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [Tabulate Area](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/tabulate-area.htm) to calculate the area of each land cover class in each county. You don't need to clip the land cover raster into several rasters based on county boundaries. You can use the same land cover raster (one file) and use the county boundaries as zone boundary to calculate the land cover area within each county boundary. the output from tabulate area tool will be a table that directly calculate the area, and the unit depends on the projection used in your data.

Please note that tabulate area tool requires Spatial Analyst extension.